# Eclipse stays in waiting to install state in the software Center

Tags: installation, eclipse

I downloaded Eclipse from Software Center but after the download, it says `waiting to install`. 
I am totally confused. 
It should have installed after download according to all sources but it isn't.
What seems to be the problem?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Could you tell if the Software Center displays any errors when you open the list of applications waiting to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

'lock' is a file. Whenever package is being installed from terminal or package managers like Ubuntu software center, this file is being used for locking so that no one else can install another package concurrently. Whenever you try to install package concurrently, it tells you another package manager is using this file.So with lsof command it list contents being downloaded or used by package manager.

From there I identified the PID of the process causing my dpkg to lock. Then I did

```
sudo kill -TERM <PID>
```

So you get  of downloading process and you     kill it.

Next, I did a

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and waited for the result... after that i did a regular.This configures (`--configure`) all the packages (`-a`) which are yet unpacked and unconfigured, using `dpkg`.)

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

`sudo apt-get update` synchronizes your list of available packages with the servers in source repositories.
`sudo apt-get upgrade` then downloads & installs any newer versions of your installed progs.

Comment: could you explain those commands meaning ?

Comment: @Jai I have edited my post for understanding the process!